# Overview Feature Extraction in images?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, references, dimensionality-reduction, feature-engineering

I have been searching for deep feature extraction approaches for a while now, but I did not find a single paper giving me a coarse overview on this matter.

Apart from an overview, for example I would like to read about using the encoder of an autoencoder as a feature extractor.

Does somebody know any papers on this topic? Thank you in advance for any answers!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are papers about feature extraction, probably there are only for single components to be applied into AE in order to reduce reconstruction error. Besides that, if you want to extract features from an image I also suggest an AE using the following approach

1. Train AE to reconstruct images
2. Get encoder and use that to find meaningful features

Another valid alternative (prolly better) is to use pretrained models on images like VGG16, ResNet etc. which you can download inside tensorflow/pytorch and use directly them on your images to extract deep features (keep in mind that resolution of images most of the time should be 224x224 to work with these models)

Comment: Why do you think that there are no papers about feature extraction? I did find a few papers, but they were not very helpful to me, so I thought maybe there are some great papers out there that I just did not find yet.